# Xcode 7 "Extra argument 'error' in call" Core Data Error

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode7

I was experimenting with Xcode Core Data and I came across a problem.

Here is the link to the tutorial I was using: [LINK](https://youtu.be/3IDfgATVqHw?list=FLqWJGMsszd7tQf-dG_mZSXA&t=1234)

I also would like to mention that I tried googling this and have had no luck figuring it out for myself. Hopefully one of you guys could help me out here.

### Error Line

The following line of code: "var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)"
has been giving me the warning "Extra argument 'error' in call"

### My steps towards trying to fix this:

- do try catch
- use Xcode 7

My code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class vcMain: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var txtUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtPassword: UITextField!

    @IBAction func btnSave(){
        let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

        newUser.setValue("Test Username", forKey: "username")
        newUser.setValue("Test Password", forKey: "password")

        //saves
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {}


        print(newUser)
        print("Object Saved.")
    }

    @IBAction func btnLoad(){
        let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

        // currently being worked on to restore saved data

        var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
        if (results.count > 0) {
            for res in results{
                print(res)
            }
        } else {
            print("0 results returned... Potential Error")
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API does not take additional parameter. The prototype in swift is-

```
func executeFetchRequest(_ request: NSFetchRequest) throws -> [AnyObject]
```

This call can potentially throw exceptions if there is any issue. So you will need to enclose this in a do..try and handle the exception as needed.

Change the line

```
   var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
```

to

```
   var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request)
```

Comment: I have tried removing the "error: nil" parameter although it still gives me the problem. I'm assuming that I should do that with both the do+try+handle but even after that it gave me even more errors. Maybe I'm not writing it out currently... I'll be back later on to post that piece.